# Is it possible to use theme_table on each key of array?

Tags: theming

I know [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) only accepts rows when `$row=array();` I have an array like:
**Array(
[0] => 'one',
[1](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) => 'two',
)**
Is it possible to have table rows as 'one', 'two', etc...
**I mean, first row will be 'one',
second row will be 'two'.**

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

After few minutes, I realized it was so simple.

```
$rows[] = array('data' => array($row));
```

where $row wasn't array, it is array key.